# Left pad zeroes to a string variable in java

Tags: java, string

I have a string variable of 10 digits, if something less than 10 i need to append '0' before the variable. Example if the string is 9909909 it should be returned as 0009909909. how to do it in java

Comment: http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/sprintf/

Comment: String.format("%010d", Integer.parseInt(mystring));

Answer (score 13):

You can use `leftPad` function of `StringUtils`
So, it will look like this:

```
StringUtils.leftPad(myString, 10,"0");
```

Comment: is there a situation that leftpad fails to add '0's ?

Answer (score 12):

Try Apache StringUtils class.

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;
...

String seqNumber = "123"
int seqNumberLength = 10;
String result = StringUtils.leftPad(seqNumber, seqNumberLength,"0")
```

result is 0000000123

Answer (score 8):

There is some ways to do this. You can test performance of these methods creating unit tests. You'll need to test this by yourself: I wrote it without any kind of compilation:

1. Use the Apache StringUtils package;

   ```
   StringUtils.leftPad(yourString, 10, "0");
   ```
2. A trick to avoid a for/while statement:

   ```
   String newString = "0000000000".concat(yourString);
   newString = newString.substring(newString.length() - 10);
   ```
3. A trick using replace:

   ```
   String newString = String.format("%10s", youString).replace(" ", "0");
   ```
4. Using a classic while with StringBuilder:

   ```
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(yourString);
   int charsToGo = 10 - sb.length();
   while(charsToGo > 0) {
      sb.insert(0, '0');
      charsToGo--;
   }
   ```

You could encapsulate this developing a StringUtils class to avoid importing too many packages.

Comment: I know this is ancient, but I had to pad a hex string to 16 chars for a project, and figured I'd add my performance test results. Results are the number of milliseconds it took to perform the padding for a given number of cycles

short input (1 char) - 123 cycles
left pad 9
sbAppend 0
substr 14
long input (15 char) - 123 cycles
left pad 0
sbAppend 0
substr 1
short input (1 char) - 1234 cycles
left pad 1
sbAppend 2
substr 3
long input (15 char) - 1234 cycles
left pad 0
sbAppend 1
substr 1
short input (1 char) - 12345 cycles
left pad 2
sbAppend 8
substr 6

Comment: (cont)
long input (15 char) - 12345 cycles
left pad 2
sbAppend 1
substr 4
short input (1 char) - 123456 cycles
left pad 25
sbAppend 29
substr 22
long input (15 char) - 123456 cycles
left pad 5
sbAppend 13
substr 9
short input (1 char) - 1234567 cycles
left pad 65
sbAppend 135
substr 52
long input (15 char) - 1234567 cycles
left pad 67
sbAppend 59
substr 57
short input (1 char) - 12345678 cycles
left pad 494
sbAppend 806
substr 292

Comment: (cont2)
long input (15 char) - 12345678 cycles
left pad 403
sbAppend 298
substr 305
short input (1 char) - 123456789 cycles
left pad 5048
sbAppend 8281
substr 3064
long input (15 char) - 123456789 cycles
left pad 3998
sbAppend 2997
substr 3067
short input (1 char) - 1234567890 cycles
left pad 48295
sbAppend 83530
substr 31823
long input (15 char) - 1234567890 cycles
left pad 44088
sbAppend 32023
substr 30985

Answer (score 7):

This should do ya:

```
System.out.println("Number: " + String.format("%010d", 1));
```

The 'format string' portion given is defined here:
http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax

Comment: Unfortunately this does not answer the question: pad a *string* with zeros.

Comment: Ah - I missed that.  If it is a number stored in a string Integer.valueOf(str) can be used to convert it first.  Otherwise I'd suggest using the Apache [StringUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html).

Comment: If you update your answer with `Integer.parseInt()` then this is a good response.

Answer (score 6):

[Google Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) has method [`Strings.padStart()`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Strings.html#padStart%28java.lang.String,%20int,%20char%29) for this purpose:

> Returns a string, of length at least minLength, consisting of string prepended with as many copies of padChar as are necessary to reach that length. For example,
>
> padStart("7", 3, '0') returns "007"
>
> padStart("2010", 3, '0') returns "2010"

Answer (score 2):

1. Get the size of the string - String.size();
2. if size is less than 10 then create a string with zeroes (however many you need). You can loop through.
3. Concatenate the two string - with the "zeros string" being the first one.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

This will take an arbitrary string with arbitrary padding character

```
public static String lpad(String s, int desiredLength, char padChar) {
  return Character.toString(padChar)
    .repeat(Math.max(0, desiredLength - s.length())) 
    + s;
}
```

This will take in a Number, Integer, Long, BigInteger

```
String.format("%032d", number); // 0-padded to 32 characters
```

But in case you're coming here to deal with message digest hashes

```
byte[] digestBytes = messageDigest.digest();
String.format("%032X", new BigInteger(1, digestBytes));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int value = 5;
String strValue = "" + value;

while (strValue.length() < 10) {
  strValue = "0" + strValue;
}

// strValue now equals "0000000005"
```

- Replace `value` with whatever your actual number is
- Replace `10` with whatever your limit is (if it's a fixed limit, consider using a `final` variable)
- If this is a speed-critical operation, instead of plain String concatenation, consider using a [StringBuffer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html) or [StringBuilder](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html).

---

Comment: I would argue that regardless if it's speed-critical or not you should use a `StringBuilder`.

Answer (score 0):

```
int zeroesNeeded = 10 - myString.length();
while(zeroesNeeded > 0)
{
   myString = "0" + myString;
   zeroesNeeded--;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i=0; i<(10-str.length); i++) {
    str = "0" + str;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `StringBuilder` and prepend zeroes until you get the desired length.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(myString);
while (sb.length() < 10)
{
    sb.insert(0,'0');
}
myString = sb.toString();
```