# How to add Zero before the name depending on name lenght

Tags: java

i am doing a sample program where i need to get the values from database as example candidatename and to write a .txt file and this part is ok for me. my problem is in .txt file the name value is fixed length so i need to add some 0 before the name to fulfil that condition . for example my name lenght in .txt file is 10 char and if my name is "amar" then i need to add some 0 before the name as "0000000amar". i am attaching my code bellow

```
  package com.myapp.struts.Action;




 public class Main {


 public static final long RECORD_LENGTH = 100;
 public static final String EMPTY_STRING = " ";
public static final String CRLF = "\n";
public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {

  String a="";
  String q="";

  PrintWriter writer=null;
  try
  {
  File file=new File("c:/report");
  file.mkdirs();
  Connection connection = mbjBaseDAO.getConnection();
  Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
  String query="select candidate_name from online_application ";
  ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery(query);
  while(rs.next())
  {
      a=rs.getString("candidate_name");
      int lenght=a.length();
      System.out.println("lenght is"+lenght);


      System.out.println(q);

      writer=new PrintWriter("c:/report/challan.txt");
      for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
      {
         writer.print(q+"\t");
         if((i)==i)
         {
             writer.println();
         }
      }
  }
  }
  catch(Exception e)
  {
      e.printStackTrace();
  }
  finally
  {
      writer.flush();
      writer.close();
    }



}



 public static String paddingRight(String source)
 {
  StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(100);
 if(source != null)
 {
    result.append(source);
    for (int i = 0; i < RECORD_LENGTH - source.length(); i++)
    {
        result.append(EMPTY_STRING);
    }
}

return result.toString();
```

}
}

Please help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/473282/how-can-i-pad-an-integers-with-zeros-on-the-left?rq=1

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7970615/left-pad-zeroes-to-a-string-variable-in-java

Comment: @ASADUL - you're not texting on a cell phone :) Perhaps you could utilize capitalization and punctuation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String str = "amar";
str = String.format("%11s", str).replace(' ', '0');
System.out.println(str); // 0000000amar
```